# Restarting animation when I touch a button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview

I need to restart my animation when I click a button.

This is the code of the my animation:

```
imgStar.frame = CGRectMake(205, 6, imgStar.frame.size.width, imgStar.frame.size.height);    
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinished:finished:context:)];
    imgStar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-4, 340);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

The problem is that: when I re-click(click for the second time) my button the animation don't work!

Can you help me, please?

Comment: why this animation the second time don't work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The error is imgStar.transform. I try to use this code:

```
[imgStar setFrame:CGRectOffset([imgStar frame], -4, 340)];
```

instead of

```
imgStar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-4, 340);
```

and now it work!!